# List of all available actions in Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Where do I get the list of all available actions in Google Home?

I don't want to write an action if there is an existing action for the same purpose. I can search for a skill in Alexa skills. I am not sure how to do that in Google Home.

Answer (score 1):

Google recently launched a new [Directory](https://assistant.google.com/explore/) to help users discover Assistant actions.

Actions are organized by categories (what's popular, what's trending, Sports, Entertainment, Business, etc) and are searchable.

[image]

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a direct link myself, but [according](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/google-home-complete-list-of-commands/) to CNET:

> You can find the full list of Actions in the Google Home app by going to More settings > Services.

Google [describes](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/directory) some "Mobile app directory" featuring Assistant apps ("actions"?):

> The mobile app directory lets users browse for available features and services on the Google app for Android and the Google Assistant app for iOS.

No link.

Google Assistant for iOS shows some hints in settings. No complete list found.

Some confirmed examples from the same CNET article:

> 21 Blackjack: "OK Google, let me talk to 21 Blackjack."
>
> Best Dad Jokes: "OK Google, talk to Best Dad Jokes."
>
> Domino's: "OK Google, talk to Domino's and get my Easy Order."
>
> Product Hunt: "OK Google, talk to Product Hunt."
>
> Tender: "OK Google, can I talk to Tender about drinks like an old
>   fashioned?"
>
> Todoist: "OK Google, tell me what my next task is with Todoist."